# Automapper with EF Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I'm trying to map two collections by using EF's navigation property.

`Collection.Items` is a `List<Item>`

`CollectionDTO` has a navigation property to a cross-join table called `CollectionItem`, which has another navigation property to `Item`.

I want each `CollectionDTO.CollectionItem.Item` to map to `Collection.Item`.

I have tried this but I can't figure it out.

Can someone help?

```
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    // CreateMap<source, destination>()    
    cfg.CreateMap<Collection, CollectionDTO>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Items,
                   opts => opts.MapFrom(src =>
                       src.CollectionItems.Where(x => x.CollectionId == src.Id).ToList().ForEach(ci => ci.Item)));

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Select` extension method like this:

```
// CreateMap<source, destination>()    
    cfg.CreateMap<Collection, CollectionDTO>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.Items,
                   opts => opts.MapFrom(src =>
                       src.CollectionItems.Select(ci=>ci.Item).ToList()));
```

If `Item` navigation property is a collection, then use `SelectMany` extension method:

```
// CreateMap<source, destination>()    
    cfg.CreateMap<Collection, CollectionDTO>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.Items,
                   opts => opts.MapFrom(src =>
                       src.CollectionItems.SelectMany(ci=>ci.Item).ToList()));
```

Comment: The second option was giving me compile errors but the first option worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome ;). That's what I guessed, that `CollectionItems` represents a junction table and `Item` is a reference navigation property.